# Остановить event loop выполнить свою задачу и снова запустить этот же event loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, асинхронность, asyncio

У меня есть фреймворк, который создаёт `event loop`. Я не могу это никак изменить. Мой код импортируется в этот event loop и выполняется там. Мне нужно в своём коде выполнить одну задачу. Но не всё так просто.

**Я пробовал:**

```
import asyncio
""" Здесь из библиотеки имортируется асинхронная функция """
from library import library_function


""" Функция, которую мне нужно выполнить, она должна быть асинхронной """
async def my_function()
    global result
    result = await library_function()


""" Получить event loop, созданный фреймворком """
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
""" Добавить мою функцию в event loop """
loop.create_task(my_function())

""" !!! Нельзя, чтобы эта часть кода начала выполняться, пока не будет выполнена моя функция !!!
    Но она начинает выполняться, потому что моя задача стоит после текущей задачи. А текущая
    задача это как раз выполнение этого файла.
    Нельзя использовать await, т.к. будет ошбика, что await используется вне функции.
    Как быть? """
```

**Мои идеи:**

1. Остановить текущий `current_event_loop` создать `new_event_loop`, выполнить мою задачу в `new_event_loop` и удалить его. Продолжить выполнение `current_event_loop`. Проблема - `current_event_loop` никак не реагирует на `current_event_loop.stop()` и продолжает выполняться. Метод `close()` остановит его, но тогда его больше никак не запустить
2. Остановить `current_event_loop` с помощью метода `close`, достать из него задачи и поместить в `new_event_loop`. Но как получить задачи из `current_event_loop`? Не нашёл ничего ни в свойствах класса ни в методах. Искал с помощью `dir()` и читал официальную документацию

Comment: А что это за фреймворк и как все организовано с точки зрения потоков?

Comment: @mkkik fastapi, в этом же файле, только ниже мною создаётся экземпляр класса app. Он экспортируется из моего файла в event loop. Мне нужно указать свойства этого экземпляра, но для этого мне нужно выполнить асинхронную функцию до объявления свойства